# Error setting up SMTP via Exim4

Tags: smtp, email-server, exim, microsoft-office-365

I just started at my current role and I'm the only IT guy...

I have a server that is used to send emails to a local smarthost but they just switched to using Office 365 and it "never worked" since then...

I googled it but I cannot really "tell" what I'm doing wrong (I've never used Exim4 before now...)

When P look at the maillog I see a bunch of things like this and its not sending...

```
it_alert@email.com <root@server> R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (-53): retry time not reached for any host for 'email.com'
```

I've edited the `/etc/exim4/passwd.client` file to have the correct email and password and I have edited the `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` to have the smtp server as smtp.office365.com:587

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

so after changing some things in the config this is what it shows when i do a mail root

```
Admin@server:~$ sudo tail /var/log/exim4/mainlog
2022-02-25 12:23:57 1nNeJx-0000Tl-GC => :blackhole: <root@server> R=system_aliases
2022-02-25 12:23:57 1nNeJx-0000Tl-GC Completed
2022-02-25 12:30:51 1nNeQd-0000uu-2f <= Admin@server U=Admin P=local S=442
2022-02-25 12:30:51 1nNeQd-0000uu-2f => :blackhole: <root@Server> R=system_aliases
2022-02-25 12:30:51 1nNeQd-0000uu-2f Completed
2022-02-25 12:52:52 Start queue run: pid=7812
2022-02-25 12:52:52 End queue run: pid=7812
2022-02-25 13:03:01 1nNevl-0002Zg-Ri <= Admin@server U=Admin P=local S=442
2022-02-25 13:03:01 1nNevl-0002Zg-Ri => :blackhole: <root@server> R=system_aliases
2022-02-25 13:03:01 1nNevl-0002Zg-Ri Completed
```

but i never get any emails to the email i have it "set" to send to... any ideas?

Comment: For that particular error: [`exinext [user@]example.com`](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-exim_utilities.html#SECTfinindret) might be useful but such errors are more a symptom rather than linked to specific error/misconfiguration. You will need to dig deeper in the logs.

Comment: Im updating the initial bit above.